# Logical Connectiveness

Tags: logic, quantifiers

$∃b∈S2 ∀a∈S1 :p(a,b)$

This is my attempt: 
$(x,y)∈ $ {$[ (a,c)∧ (b,c) ] ∨ [(a,d)∧ (a,d) ] $} | (P(x,y)

Comment: Now it is impossible to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\forall x\in M_1:P(x,y)$$ is $$P(a,y)\land P(b,y),$$

and

$$\exists y\in M_2:\forall x\in M_1:P(x,y)$$ is $$(P(a,c)\land P(b,c))\lor(P(a,d)\land P(b,d)).$$

Comment: @smalllearner: hem, it wasn't ready yet. Your attempt is syntactically and semantically meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

*Not exactly*...

In *finite* domains, $\exists$ acts as a *disjunction* while $\forall$ acts as a *conjunction*.

Thus, set $y=c$; we have that $(\forall x \in M_1) P(x,y)$ will be:

> $P(a,c) \land P(b,c)$.

Now, do the same for $y=d$.